# Is the "HTC Desire (A8181)" Android 2.2 phone supported?

Tags: android, smartphone

I could not find an entry for HTC Desire in the supported Anrdoid phones so I'm just wondering if all 2.2 devices are supported or if the list is specific to phone and installed software versions etc?

Update: Android is listed generically under supported manufacturer and model but I found a stumbling block regardless of my initial query above..
*I am on the basic package ..*
On re reading (https://one.ubuntu.com/basic/) **Everyone gets the basics… for free!** 
The option to Sync contacts with a mobile phone **is for a fee**.

Comment: Can you please clarify what list you mean?

Comment: To clarify..
https://one.ubuntu.com/mobile/

Contacts sync (at bottom of page)

Sync all phone contacts with your Ubuntu One personal cloud address book "wirelessly"
Manual and automatic options
Supports Android, iPhone, Blackberry, Nokia and 1000s of other phones. Search for your phone to see if it's supported.

https://one.ubuntu.com/phones/public

Phone Finder
Manufacturers: HTC
Models: Desire (not listed)

Manufacturer: Android
Models: Android
For this phone, we support:

Comment: Oops sorry about previous response which closed before I had finished, let me clarify..  I was checking if the HTC Desire is supported for contact sync  (https://one.ubuntu.com/mobile/)

See **Contacts sync** (at bottom of page)

On selecting **Search for your phone**
(https://one.ubuntu.com/phones/public)

**Phone Finder**
Manufacturers: HTC             
Models:                        Desire not listed
On a second look I found 
Manufacturer: Android
Models: Android
**For this phone we support music sync**

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to know if Ubuntu recognize HTC Desire, the answer is yes.
I can't think of anything else that would make it "supported".

Comment: Many thanks for the response Chriskin. I know the simple thing to do would be to try and set it up but my reluctance comes from an issue while sync was in beta. I tried  it and it caused a Nokia to lock up and do strange things. Don't want to cause any problems on my precious Desire :-) so was hoping to find out if anyone else is using it on the HTC Desire. On a second look at the supported phones I did find a generic entry _Android_ under **Manufacture** and _Android_ under associated **Model** which gives me a little more confidence, my original search was specifically for _HTC_ and _Desire_

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there are no native Ubuntu applications for HTC Desire (I am an owner of HTC Desire :) ). The only  thing I could say is that HTC Desire is supported by media players (like Banshee), so you are able to sync music files. I would like also backup/restore contact information in HTC Desire. So please let me know if you find a solution.

Good luck.

Comment: wammu/gammu can probably do that for you

Comment: I checked Gammu support, yet there are no HTC Android phones supported by Gammu.

Comment: strange - i am pretty sure i have connected to mine from there. You can always use google's sync , by the way. It will backup your contacts to gmail

Comment: I do not want to sync my contacts with public services. I would be glad having offline copy of contacts and SMS messages.

Comment: Thanks for response Vincenzo. Tend to agree with your comment on public service sync, I would have a reluctance to give google any more information than they already collect on me without my express knowledge or permission however I would be far more inclined to sync on UbuntuOne. Not sure what Gammu is but will use **Alta Vista** :-) to find it and check it out.

Comment: @Peter. I would like to find a solution for HTC Desire backup in Ubuntu. Please let me know if you find something useful.

Comment: Vincenzo, re backups.. I'm not sure if it will do what you want but I have been using MobileSMB to copy my phones SD contents to an old Samba NAS drive over my WiFi.  There is a bug that prevents it from doing everything in one go. The developer thinks its down the the Samba Version on the NAS and is working on a fix.  My guess is that it should also copy to an Ubuntu machine with Samba running but I have not tried it.

Comment: Dear Peter, I think that the best solution for HTC (Android) Address Book backup is just to perform a backup of AddressBook to SD card by mean of Android phone itself (it will backup all address books (separately) in CVS format files). This is one of possible 'backup plans' :) for address books.